# Sleuth 3.0.x - outbox pattern support - materializing persisted Spans - reactive pipeline

Tags: reactor, spring-cloud-sleuth

We have a fully reactive spring webflux microservice.
We are using an Outbox pattern for guaranteed asynchronous processing of persisted events.
Each event is stored with its original `Span` data (traceId, spanId, ...).
A `Scheduler` subscribes to a pipeline which reads unprocessed events and runs a specific processor pipeline for each of them.
When processing an event - we want to "materialize" the persisted `Span` and push it into the running pipeline subscriber context - so that all the activities with such event can be tracked.

**Questions**

1. Is there an official/documented way of inserting the crafted `Span` into the actual pipeline context so that the ScopePassingOperator could handle it?
2. Starting with Sleuth 3.0.0 - how to materialize a `Span` from particles? All the new Sleuth bridge classes carefully hide `fromBrave` conversion methods.
   So you have to rely on some dirty reflection or use `MessagingSleuthOperators` which won't let you set the proper span kind ... :-(

Regards Jan

Comment: It would be best if you create a small sample that we could check and play around with. Is there an option to prepare one?